# ruby curb запрос с русскими буквами

Tags: http, ruby, curl

Использую библиотеку curb языка руби(ruby 2.3.6p384 [x86_64-linux]). Надо спарсить сайт, где в адресной строке используется кириллица(буквы алфавита), наподобие "[https://adress.com/abc.php?abc=ч](https://adress.com/abc.php?abc=%D1%87)", передаю запрос

```
http = Curl.get('https://adress.com/abc.php?abc=%D1%87')  #%D1%87 => UTF-8
```

но мне возвращает объект

```
=> #<Curl::Easy https://adress.com/abc.php?>  

#без передоваемого параметра - буквы Ч
```

Как передать значение русских букв правильно?

---

Ps Использовал напрямую curl:

```
curl -G "https://adress.com/abc.php?abc=%D1%87"
```

страница возвращаеться корректно.

---

да, парсится первоначальная страница с буквой "А", аргумент "Ч" не воспринимает.
Дальше я работаю с `Nokogiri::HTML(http.body_str)`, но дело не в нем, т.к. http.body_str уже отображает страницу с буквой А.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пришел к результату, что нужно было передавать параметры вручную:

```
http = Curl.get(@url, params={ abc:'ч' })
```